# How to get the emails out in the table from the given link when email is listed as a link?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I have a website that enlists table, I need to scrape the table. In that table the email addresses present can be seen only when we open them in new tab but they are present in the html script of the page. I am unable to scrape the emails.

```
class HTMLTableParser:    
  def parse_url(self,url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    return[(table['id'], self.parse_html_table(table))\
          for table in soup.find_all('table')]

  def parse_html_table(self,table):
     n_columns = 0
     n_rows = 0
     column_names = []

     for row in table.find_all('tr'):
         td_tags = row.find_all('td')
         if len(td_tags)>0:
             n_rows+=1
             if n_columns == 0:
                 n_columns = len(td_tags)

         th_tags = row.find_all('th')
         if len(th_tags) > 0 and len(column_names) == 0:
             for th in th_tags:
                 column_names.append(th.get_text())




    if len(column_names) > 0 and len(column_names) != n_columns:
        raise Exception("Column titles do not match the number of columns")

    columns = column_names if len(column_names) > 0 else range(0, n_columns)

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns,
                     index = range(0, n_rows))

    row_marker = 0
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        column_marker = 0
        columns = row.find_all('td')
        for column in columns:
            df.iat[row_marker, column_marker] = column.get_text()
            column_marker += 1
        if len(columns) > 0:
            row_marker += 1

    for col in df:
        try:
            df[col] = df[col].astype(float)
        except ValueError:
            pass

    return df
```

Comment: Please post the HTML of the page you're trying to scrape.

Comment: Here's the link - https://www.adelaide.edu.au/directory/atoz?dsn=directory.phonebook;orderby=last%2Cfirst%2Cposition_n;m=atoz;page=;perpage=50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Originally I only answered how to get at just the email. Answer adjusted to get the email with all the other data.
EDIT 2: Compatible with BS4 4.6 series.

The email cannot be acquired because it is found in the `href` of an anchor. We will extract the email from the anchor if it is found, else we will extract the the text from the cell if the email is not.

As it isn't exactly clear to me 100% what the code's end goal is, this is only looking at extracting all the cells, with am emphasis on acquiring the email that was not captured in the original code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.adelaide.edu.au/directory/atoz?dsn=directory.phonebook;orderby=last%2Cfirst%2Cposition_n;m=atoz;page=;perpage=50'

def parse_url(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    return [(table['id'], parse_html_table(table)) for table in soup.find_all('table')]

def parse_html_table(table):
    n_columns = 0
    n_rows = 0
    column_names = []

    column_names = [th.get_text() for th in table.select('th')]
    n_columns = len(column_names)

    rows = table.select('tr')[1:]
    n_rows = len(rows)

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names, index=range(n_rows))

    r_index = 0
    for row in rows:
        c_index = 0
        for cell in row.select('td'):
            if cell.get('data-th') == 'Email':
                anchor = cell.select_one('a')
                df.iat[r_index, c_index] = anchor.get('href').replace('mailto:', '') if anchor else cell.get_text()
            else:
                df.iat[r_index, c_index] = cell.get_text()
            c_index += 1
        r_index += 1

    return df

print(parse_url(url))
```

Comment: Thanks, this was great

Comment: @Albert don't forget to accept the answer if you feel it answered your question.

Comment: Hey, when I added this to the loop I can get the emails out separately but I am not able to get it out in the dataframe that I am exporting

Comment: I apologize, I was originally just answering out to get the email. The original code you posted wouldn't even compile, but I'll update the answer.

Comment: I've posted an updated answer. I particularly focused just on extracting the data. anything not related to that was stripped out.

Comment: When running the code I get an error "NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type." I tried changing to nth of child but I guess I am doing something wrong

Comment: The answer requires BS4 4.7+.

Comment: I just updated to the latest and it says 4.6.3, can you please guide me how to get 4.7+. I really appreciate your assistance

Comment: What environment are you in? Pip should give you the latest, but if you are doing it through some other environment, I may not be able to help.

Comment: I'll rephrase, if you can't upgrade to 4.7, for 4.6 you'd have to rework the logic for the selector `tr:has(td)`, everything else should work. You can search for all `tr` elements skipping the first.

Comment: I've updated with 4.6 compatibility. It should work with 4.6.3 now. Hopefully that gets you were you need to be.

Comment: Thanks, I did not find 4.7+ so I edited the code and removed the noise from the output. I am using pip but still am able to get 4.6.3 version.

Comment: I'm using 4.7, not sure why you aren't seeing it, maybe need to update pip?  Anyways, the solution now works for 4.6 for me. Hopefully it helped, if not, I gave it a good try :).